# "Type or namespace could not be found" for custom NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard

I'm trying to save a project as a custom NuGet package that I can reference from other projects/solutions. My solution structure is as follows.

```
Solution
 |   
 +-- Project1
 |  |  
 |  +-- References
       |
       +-- Package (Project2.DLL)   
 |       
 +-- Project2
```

As you can see, I'm trying to package Project2 up as a NuGet package that I can reference from Project1.

My .nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Package</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>CHull</authors>
    <owners>CHull</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <references>
          <reference file="Project2.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="src\Project2\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\Project2.dll" target="lib"></file>
  </files>
</package>
```

After running the pack command, I am able to see this package in the NuGet package manager, and can install it to Project1. When I install it to Project1, it appears in my references as expected, but when I try to add

```
using Package;
```

I get the "Type or namespace could not be found" error.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why it can't find "Package", and I'm out of ideas of what to even look for.

Help!

Comment: Are both projects targetting the same Framework? And is `Package` a valid root namespace?

Comment: Yes, both projects are targeting .net standard 1.6. I'm not sure if Package itself valid, but I had the same issue when giving the package the actual project name, which is definitely valid.

Comment: You need to import a namespace, not a project name.